# I'm having trouble implementing a "y or n" function to build an argument that is passed on to a bash script on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot that handles requests for image generation for stable diffusion and I'm having issues with the argument building function I'm trying to implement. The bot asks if the user wants an argument to be used, for example "--plms" and will skip or add depending on the response to the "y or n" question. However, when responding with n, the argument is still present on the final result.

```
predetermined_arguments = [
    {"name": "quoted_argument", "question": "Enter the quoted argument:", "type": str},
    {"name": "plms_option", "question": "Use --plms option? (y/n)", "type": bool},
    {"name": "skip_grid_option", "question": "Use --skip_grid option? (y/n)", "type": bool},
    {"name": "n_samples_value", "question": "Enter the value for --n_samples (or leave empty for 0):", "type": int}
]

@bot.command()
async def request(ctx):
    try:
        user_responses = {}
        for arg in predetermined_arguments:
            question = arg["question"]
            response = await ask_question(ctx, question)
            user_responses[arg["name"]] = arg["type"](response)

        # Construct the bash command based on user responses
        bash_command = ["run.sh"]
        if user_responses["quoted_argument"]:
            bash_command.append(f'"{user_responses["quoted_argument"]}"')
        if user_responses["plms_option"]:
            bash_command.append('--plms')
        if user_responses["skip_grid_option"]:
            bash_command.append('--skip_grid')
        if user_responses["n_samples_value"]:
            bash_command.extend(['--n_samples', str(user_responses["n_samples_value"])])
            
        # Run the bash script with the arguments
        subprocess.run(bash_command, check=True)
        await ctx.send("Request processed successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"Error processing request: {e}")

async def ask_question(ctx, question):
    await ctx.send(question)

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    try:
        response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60)
        return response.content
    except TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("You took too long to respond. Request canceled.")
        return None
```

The prompt and --n_samples arguments work as intended but I cant figure out how to get the bot to "remove" the --skip_grid and --plms arguments when prompted "n".

Comment: From what I can see, `user_responses["plms_option"]` is equal to bool('y') or bool('n'), which is True in both cases! You probably want to change your logic, for example `if user_responses["plms_option"] == 'y':`

Comment: @Swifty I added `if user_responses["plms_option"] == 'y' ` but it's still not quite working for me.

Comment: Did you change the type to "str" too? If you can't make it work, you can debug by adding a `print(user_responses["plms_option"])` after the `if ...` to see exactly how the answer comes out, then adjust the test.